# Navigation bar color is not under status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift3

I am trying to make a transparent navigation bar, but when I set it to transparent It looks like this... :
[image: transparent]

I want it to look like this 
[image: non-transparent]

but transparent and blurred like in the App Store but with background color. The problem is that the background color of the navigation controller is not under status bar like normal.

My code:

```
 self.navigationItem.title = "label"
 self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
 self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
 self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
 self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7)
```

EDIT: I have a custom class for `UINavigationController` and the view controller is embedded in a `UINavigationController`

Swift 3, Xcode 8.0 beta 5.

Comment: Is your view controller in embedded in a `UINavigationController` or does it have a `UINavigationBar` added as a subview on the view?

Comment: It is embedded in a UINavigationController

Comment: You have a custom `UINavigationController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`? Why? Can we see the code for the custom `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Class: https://imgur.com/a/NAd6p, Storyboard: https://imgur.com/a/2AgcM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this problem into parts. First, you will need to use a `UIVisualEffectView` created with a `UIBlurEffect` to get the  blurred/transparent effect that you want. Then you will need to figure out how to display that in the navigation bar so that it fills the whole nav bar and that status bar.

**Part 1**

I created a subclass of `UIVisualEffectView` in order to add a gradient. We can use this view to create the desired blurred/transparent effect.

```
class GradientVisualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView {

    private let gradient: CAGradientLayer = {
        // You can tweak these colors and their alpha to get the desired gradient.
        // You can also mess with the gradient's locations.
        $0.colors = [
            UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor, 
            UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7).cgColor
        ]
        return $0
    } (CAGradientLayer())


    override init(effect: UIVisualEffect?) {
        super.init(effect: effect)
        layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Make sure the gradient's frame always matches the blur effect.
        gradient.frame = bounds
    }

}
```

**Part 2**

Now we need to use this view in the nav bar. I did this in a `UIViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Remove the nav bar's background
    let navBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
    navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navBar.backgroundColor = .clear

    // Create the blur/transparent view. You can mess with styles here to get
    // different effects.
    let gradientBlur = GradientVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
    gradientBlur.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    navBar.addSubview(gradientBlur)

    // Constrain the view so that it always matches the nav bar.
    // The top constraint has a -20 constant so that it will extend above
    // the nav bar to the status bar.
    gradientBlur.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBar.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    gradientBlur.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBar.topAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    gradientBlur.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBar.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    gradientBlur.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Below is a picture of the result from my simulator. You can see some blurred text at the top left of the picture, where the white part of the status bar looks darker.

[image: blurred/transparent nav bar]

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Comment: hard coding the `-20` breaks on iPhoneX and it probably a bad idea